# Sending Message to WPF app

Tags: wpf, windows, message

I am trying to send a message to a WPF application to have it Minimize and then to restore

I am doing

```
//Import the SetForeground API to activate it
[DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);

[DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")]
//private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, bool wParam, int lParam);
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
....


 SetForegroundWindow(hWnd); //Activate it

 //in here I minimize the window manually
 SendMessage(hWnd, 0x0018, (UIntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0); //trying to restore
```

it does not work

Any ideas

Comment: Have you used Spy++ to check if the window is receiving the message?

Comment: yes I have and I see it there... - it says WM_SHOWWINDOW fshow:false fuStatus:0      I thought I may have a parameter wrong but then i would expect it to minimize which it doesnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably better off importing ShowWindow rather than just SendMessage:

```
[DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")] 
private static extern IntPtr ShowWindow(int hWnd, int showFlag);

public const int SW_MINIMIZE = 0x06;
pubilc const int SW_RESTORE = 0x09;
public const int SW_FORCEMINIMIZE = 0x0B;
```

You should then just be able to say `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MINIMIZE);` etc.